# Using a For...Next Loop to Write Values which Depend Upon the Counter

Tags: vba, excel

I want to write "1" in a specified number of cells in column E, and then "2" in the same number of cells directly below the cells with 1 in them, and then "3", and so on, until the value I'm writing in the cells reaches a user-defined variable. I *think* I should be using a For...Next loop for this, but I'm not sure. The code I have now is this:

```
    Dim k As Long
    For k = 0 To observations
        Range(Cells(2 + (k * patientprofiles), 5), Cells(1 + p * (k + 1), 5)).Value = k + 1
    Next
```

where `observations` is the value that I want to write in the cells, and `patientprofiles` is the number of cells to fill before moving to the next value. For example, if `observations` is 6 and `patientprofiles` is 40, I want to write 1 in cells E2:E41, 2 in cells E42:E81, 3 in cells E82:E121, 4 in cells E122:E161, 5 in cells E162:E201 and 6 in cells E202:E241.

The code I have above is writing 7 in cells E1:E242, i.e., it's not changing the value it's writing as it moves through the loop, and it's starting in E1 and finishing in E242 instead of starting in E2 and finishing in E241.

I have three questions about this:

1. Am I correct in thinking that I should be using a For...Next loop to do this? If not, what should I be using?
2. If For...Next is the right approach, how can I get VBA to write a different value in each of the cells, rather than the same one in all cells?
3. Why is it starting a cell too high and ending a cell too low?

Thank you for your help and I apologize if this is a really simple question or if it has been answered elsewhere.

Comment: `starting in E2` because `Cells(2 + (k * patientprofiles)` tells it to start on row 2 when `k=0` (beginning of loop). Edit: oh wait, you DO want it to start on `E2`...

Comment: You have `p` in  the second `Cells` that should be `patientprofiles`

Comment: @ScottCraner Well that's an embarrassing mistake! Thank you though, that helps; it's now almost working. The only problem is that it writes k+1 (in the example, 7) in the next 40 cells (i.e., E242:E281). Is there a way to get it to stop writing at E241?

Comment: `For k = 0 To observations - 1`

Answer (score 1):

You want the `.Resize()` method in conjunction with the `Step` argument for a loop:

```
Sub Foo()

Dim k                 As Long
Dim incrementValue    As Long
Const observations    As Long = 6
Const patientProfiles As Long = 40

incrementValue = 1

For k = 2 To observations * patientProfiles Step patientProfiles
    Cells(k, 5).Resize(40, 1).Value = incrementValue
    incrementValue = incrementValue + 1
Next

End Sub
```

---

The `Step` argument tells the loop to increment in steps, for example:

```
For i = 1 To 10           '// 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
For i = 1 To 10 Step 2    '// 1,3,5,7,9
For i = 1 To 10 Step 3    '// 1,4,7,10
```

---

The `Resize()` method re-sizes a range object to the given parameters:

```
Range("A1")                '// 1R x 1C
Range("A1:B5")             '// 5R x 2C
Range("A1").Resize(5, 2)   '// 5R x 2C (Now "A1:B5")
Range("B5").Resize(9, 1)   '// 9R x 1C (Now "B5:B13")
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way as below

```
Sub testttt()
    Dim k As Long
    observations = 6
    patientprofiles = 40
    For k = 0 To observations
        Range("E" & (Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1), "E" & patientprofiles + (Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)).Value = k
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: can you please mark it as solution, if its satisfies

Comment: It still has the same issue of writing an extra value for the next 40 cells, though. I figured it out with Scott Craner's help above; I had a typo, plus I had to change it to `observations - 1`. Thank you for taking the time though!

Answer (score 0):

a "formula" approach

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()

Dim observations As Long, patientprofiles As Long

observations = 6
patientprofiles = 10

ActiveSheet.Range("e2").Resize(observations * patientprofiles).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(ROWS(R2C:RC)=1,1,IF(COUNTIF(R2C:R[-1]C,R[-1]C)<" & observations & ",R[-1]C,R[-1]C+1))"

End Sub
```

which could be also written directly in excel cells with the only care to limit the cells where to put it into or add to the formula an outer "IF" condition to count the number of rows where to write the resulting number